# Unity materials - how to stop overlapping of transparent objects?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, shader, transparency

Ok, there are a lot of posts regarding this but Ive followed most of them and cant find a solution. Im a noob with shaders and I cant understand this.

I have 2 spheres that will be moving that are transparent - when their meshes overlap I want them to look like they are one - meaning they stay transparent but don't overlap each other. So far this is what I have:

[image]

Ive looked at https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-CullAndDepth.html and got this shader from https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/non-overlapping-transparency-for-several-objects.271277/, and that is how I have SOME of the overlap taken care of:

```
Shader "Custom/Diffuse ZWrite" {
    Properties
    {
        _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _MainTex ("Base (RGB) Trans (A)", 2D) = "white" {}
    }

    SubShader
    {
        Tags
        {
            // I HAD TO REMOVE THE LINE "Queue"="Transparent"
            "IgnoreProjector" = "True"
            "RenderType"      = "Transparent"

        }

        LOD 200

        // extra pass that renders to depth buffer only
        Pass
        {
            ZWrite On
            ColorMask 0
            Cull Back
        }

        UsePass "Transparent/Diffuse/FORWARD"
    }
    FallBack "Transparent"
}
```

When I switch the render queue to Alphatest I get the desired effect, however it doesn't show up when the game is played, online in scene 
[image]

I don't understand why this is, and I don't know how to solve my problem. How can I stop transparent materials overlapping?

Comment: You can take a look at `clip()` function. It is the replacement for `alphatest`. `clip()` is used to make the cutout effect like `Standard` shader in `cutout` mode. http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/130325/use-of-clip-in-alpha-cutouts.html

Comment: Could you provide an example? Sorry still learning shader scripting

Comment: Would this compile in the game also unlike alphatest?